# DataContractJsonSerializer to skip nodes with null values

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer, datacontractjsonserializer

I am using `DataContractJsonSerializer` to serialize my custom object to JSON. But i want to skip the data members whose values are `null`. If `DataMember` is `null` that node should not come in JSON string.

How can I achieve this? Give me a simple `code snippet` to work with.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the `EmitDefaultValue = false` property in the `[DataMember]` attribute. For members marked with that attribute, their values will not be output.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyType
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dcjs = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyType));
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var data = new MyType { Prop2 = "Hello" };
        dcjs.WriteObject(ms, data);

        // This will write {"Prop2":"Hello"}
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
    }
}
```