# WCF-Service: Return only part of a big object as JSON without creating a new class or contract

Tags: c#, json, web-services, wcf

So, let's assume we have an Entity `Article` which has a huge underlying data structure. We need this article on clientside for 2 Purposes:

1. Get a List of Articles only containing the most relevant attributes, e.g. id, title, price
2. Get a detailview of one article containing the whole data structure.

There's a WCF-Service method like this, producing a JSON Response:

```
Public List<Article> GetArticles(string anId, bool isMinimal)
{
    using (var client = new MyApp.Model.MyAppEntities())
    {
        var articles = new List<Article>();

        myObjects = //Linq-magic to get values from db...

        if (!isMinimal)
        {
            //add a huge datastructure from other tables to each of myObjects
            // these are vitamins, allergeens, nutrients and so on for some article.
            });
        }

        return articles;
    }
}
```

So, when isMinimal is true, the whole underlying datastructure does not get filled. But (somewhat correctly, as the method signature shows it), the whole `List<Article>` is returned, with null-values for the attributes not filled.

What I want to achieve is: Let this method return only the filled values, when isMinimal is true, and "cut out the rest from the json returned". I thought about creating a "general json response" (a string?) and then let it return the desired values, so changing the Methods signature to something like this:

```
Public List<JSONresponse> GetArticles(string anId, bool isMinimal)
{
    using (var client = new MyApp.Model.MyAppEntities())
    {
        var articles = new List<JSON>();

        myObjects = getMyObjectsFromDb();//Linq-magic to get values from db...
        //adding the whole datastructe here now...
        var articleJSON = articles.toJSON();
        if (isMinimal)
        {
            articleJSON = articleJSON.Select(s => new JSON(){ title: s.title, price: s.price, Id: s.Id});
        }

        return articleJSON;
    }
}
```

But to be honest, I have no idea if this is generally possible and so I struggle very much with this.

Because of using the wcfservices in many of my applications, i would prefer not to create another method with another contract for an Object(DTO) like `ArticleMinimal`, because there would be some overhead involved updating the service references everywhere.

Would be great if someone could help me out here!

Best Regards,
Dominik

Comment: If you just want to not emit null values, you can put `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]` on your properties.  See [DataContractJsonSerializer to skip nodes with null values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506630/datacontractjsonserializer-to-skip-nodes-with-null-values).

Comment: Thank you, I think that really fits my case the best, except there comes some overhead when changing the contracts. But well, it's wcf, so what should I do ;) IF you wnat, just makean answer out of this comment.

Comment: I suggest just marking this as a duplicate then.